# Web crawling using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How to extract data that is inside `<p>` paragraph tags and `<li>` which are under a named `<div>` class?

Comment: post a sample input.

Comment: post sample html/xml

Answer (score 3):

Use the functions [`find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) and [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = '...'

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div', {'class':'class-name'})
ps = div.find_all('p')
lis = div.find_all('li')

# print the content of all <p> tags
for p in ps:
    print(p.text)

# print the content of all <li> tags
for li in lis:
    print(li.text)
```

Comment: Awesome..Thanks a ton:-)